# Sailsjs middleware parsing res.body

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js

I am new to JS and started using sails framework. I need to parse the http res body in the middleware to put a job in the celery queue. I have tried using skipper- as per the documentation- but I always get the value of res.body as undefined. When I log the response- I get only the meta-info about the same.

Below is the middleware code I am trying- could someone pls let me know what am I doing wrong?

```
order: [
  'startRequestTimer',
  'cookieParser',
  'session',
  'requestLogger',
  'bodyParser',
  'handleBodyParserError',
  'compress',
  'methodOverride',
  'poweredBy',
  '$custom',
  'router',
  'www',
  'favicon',
  '404',
  '500'
],

requestLogger: function (req, res, next) {
    var start = (new Date().getTime());
    res.on('finish', function(){
       console.log(res.body)
    });
    return next();
},

 bodyParser: require('skipper')
```

PS: I am not hung up on skipper- it's all good as long as am able to parse the result's body. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skipper is used to parse the *request* body.  The `response` object that gets passed around in Sails (and all Express-based apps) doesn't contain an actual response, it's just a collection of methods used for *forming* a response.  Once you trigger the response with something like `res.send`, there's no easy way to intercept it.  Instead, you can use a Sails [custom response](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/custom-responses), and do anything you want to the data inside the custom response before actually sending output.  The best practice here is to use `res.ok` (the "ok" response).  So in your Sails controller, where you might do

```
res.send(someData)
```

instead, do

```
res.ok(someData)
```

and then in your `api/responses/ok.js` file, add the job to your queue or whatever you need to do.

Also, put the `config/http.js` file back the way you found it until you really do need to mess with the middleware or body parser ;-)

Comment: Responses is bad place for jobs kinda this one. Middleware the best place, so he can just replace `res` with `req.body` in him middleware and make it works.

Comment: @EugeneObrezkov that's simply not true.  `req.body` contains the body of the _request_--the data that is sent _to_ the server.  It has nothing to do with the data that the server sends back.  Express doesn't have "response" middleware like some other frameworks (e.g. Django); a middleware can (to quote Express's docs) "end the request-response cycle" by calling (for example) `res.send`, but no other middleware will be called after that.  If the goal is to manipulate the server response in some standardized way before it is sent to the client, then Sails responses are the answer.

Comment: As I understand he wants to "I need to parse the http res body". Then we discussed he made an error in `res.body` so he needs to replace with `req.body`. Maybe I got it wrong, but I think that he's trying to parse request and do nothing with response.

Comment: Thanks a tonne @sgress454! Really appreciate the response- even though after struggling for a long time- I finally settled down on invoking the celery with the res just before res.send - Occam's razor to the rescue!

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as `res.body`. Its `req.body`.

http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/request-req/req-body

Comment: Well, thanks for stating the obvious- as the question states- I wish to parse the response body that the service is returning before forwarding it to the client in the middleware (if that is at all possible). But thanks for the answer anyway.